# Why NiFi HandleHttpRespose process task count is very hight?

Tags: apache-nifi

When I connect Retry from invokeHTTP to HandleHttpRespose (or any other process) in NiFi, task count will become high (about 1,000,000 tasks/time) and response slow, what must be the reason?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the task count on HandleHttpResponse, that usually would only happen when the processor has the @ TriggerWhenEmpty annotation, which means its running all the time when no flow files are available and just doing nothing.

In general, using HandleHttpResponse with InvokeHttp is not going to work, it was made to work with HandleHttpRequest which places accepts a request, creates an entry in the HTTP Context Map, allows the flow to proceed, and then can respond to the original request with HandleHttpRequest.

InvokeHttp is a client making a connection to a server, where as HandleHttpRequest is a server that needs to send a response to a client using HandleHttpResponse. InvokeHttp does not put anything into the HTTP Context Map so there is nothing for HandleHttpRequest to do in that case.

You would typically connect the "retry" relationship of InvokeHttp in a self-loop back to InvokeHttp so it can keep retrying.

Comment: When I connect retry to any other modules, task count will become high!

Comment: Thanks @BryanBendy.
The predecessor process of InvokeHttp is HandleHttpRequest. I don't have any problem with No-Retry or Response.

Comment: I see now, this is happening because the flow file that is routed to "retry" is penalized which means it is not allowed to be processed until the Penalty Duration has passed, which is configured per processor and defaults to 30 seconds. You set Penalty Duration in InvokeHttp to something smaller like 1 sec, as long as you are ok with the retry being attempted in 1 second.